# Android finish after toast when phone landscape

Tags: android, toast, onconfigurationchanged

MainActivity -> Click Button -> SecondActivity -> Click Button(Hold phone in landscape, but in this time, the screen content is actually show in portrait) -> the screen content will temporary show in landscape, and will restore to portrait in seconds.

It seem that the onConfigurationChanged has happened, but the method onConfigurationChanged() do not actually called. Instead, the MainActivity is destroyed, and recreate.

The Question is:

Why run (Hold phone in landscape, but in this time, the screen content is actually show in portrait)

1.Toast.makeText().show();

2.finish();

And then the screen will seem to happen onConfigurationChanged, and destroy, recreate MainActivity. As the log in below.

But if I change the order to

1.finish();

2.Toast.makeText().show();

It will work normal, will not destroy,recreate MainActivity. Thanks in advance, I will appreciate that if  you take a look.

```
        I/ContentCatcher: Interceptor : Catcher list invalid for com.android.toastdemo@com.android.toastdemo.MainActivity@198995995
    Interceptor : Get featureInfo from config pick_mode
    E/MainActivity: onCreate
    E/MainActivity: onStart
    E/MainActivity: onResume
    E/MainActivity: onPause
    I/ContentCatcher: Interceptor : Catcher list invalid for com.android.toastdemo@com.android.toastdemo.SecondActivity@231501910
    Interceptor : Get featureInfo from config pick_mode
    E/SecondActivity: onCreate
    E/SecondActivity: onStart
    E/SecondActivity: onResume
    D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x72d5594400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x72e2997760
    E/MainActivity: onStop
    I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.android.toastdemo, PackageName:com.android.toastdemo
    E/SecondActivity: onPause
    E/MainActivity: onDestroy
    I/ContentCatcher: Interceptor : Catcher list invalid for com.android.toastdemo@com.android.toastdemo.MainActivity@246614170
    Interceptor : Get featureInfo from config pick_mode
    E/MainActivity: onCreate
    E/MainActivity: onStart
    E/MainActivity: onResume
    D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x72c7e8f800 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x72e2922720
    E/SecondActivity: onStop
    onDestroy
    E/MainActivity: onPause
    E/MainActivity: onStop
    onDestroy
    I/ContentCatcher: Interceptor : Catcher list invalid for com.android.toastdemo@com.android.toastdemo.MainActivity@185521768
    Interceptor : Get featureInfo from config pick_mode
    E/MainActivity: onCreate
    E/MainActivity: onStart
    E/MainActivity: onResume
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button)).setText("First");
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        }
    });

    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
}

   ... some log
}
```

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "SecondActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button)).setText("Second");
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Toast Something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    });

    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
}

... some log
```

}

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="nosensor"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Please provide a minified code example.

Comment: Already delete some log

Comment: your `application` will work in both `scape`? if yes then you have to save instances of `activity`. if not the declare scape of activity in `manifest`

Comment: If I change both activity's screenOrientation to portrait，It  also happen that the screen content will temporary show in landscape, and will restore to portrait in seconds. I want to know why this happen. But in this case, the MainActivity will not recreate, just restart.